# sandbox testing environments exist for TDD'ing command line application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line, rspec, tdd

I'm writing a command line command but want to TDD it. I'll be creating and deleting files and was wondering if there's a sandbox testing gem or something like that. I'm using ruby and rspec.

Comment: What makes you say you can't use rspec for your command line app?

Comment: sorry, i wrote my question in a hurry. what i meant was to ask for any SANDBOX environment for TDD. changing my question. sorry.

Comment: Not sure specifically what you're looking for--what would a "sandbox gem" provide you? Yu can already read/write files.

Comment: For safety. I don't want to clobber files that are already on my filesystem. So while I'm developing, I want any dangerous changes to be contained in a sandbox. I've seen something for this before but I can't remember the name of it and can't find it on google.

Comment: Do you mean a Vagrant virtual machine where if you run "rm -rf /" you'll only destroy your VM and not your system? Or do you want something that doesn't actually run your file system commands?

Comment: I want something that doesn't actually run file system commands

Comment: @JesseWolgamott a VM would actually be pretty good for this. dunno why i didn't realize that sooner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you're trying to do, but I test most of my command line Ruby by mocking out the file system and STDIN/STDOUT. Using dependency injection I often end up with something along these lines:

```
describe Add do
  it 'writes the result to standard out' do
    console = mock('STDOUT')
    console.should_receive(:puts).with('5')

    Add.new(console).execute(3,2)
  end
end

class Add
  def initialize(out = STDOUT)
    @out = out
  end

  def execute(command_line_args)
    @out.puts(command_line_args.inject(:+))
  end
end

Add.new.execute(ARGS)
```

By using default values I can inject in the test, but leave it out of the production code.

Hope that helps!

Brandon

Answer (score 0):

The template generated by the `newgem` `install_cucumber` generator uses a pattern that I like quite a bit.  Have a look at the support/env.rb and support/common.rb files it creates:

- https://github.com/drnic/newgem/blob/master/rubygems_generators/install_cucumber/templates/features/support/env.rb.erb
- https://github.com/drnic/newgem/blob/master/rubygems_generators/install_cucumber/templates/features/support/common.rb

Use of it in test looks like this:

```
in_tmp_folder do
  # The current directory is now a generated tmp folder.
  # If you stick to relative paths, everything you do in here should be safe
end
```

The files linked to above are for using this in cucumber tests, but it could easily be adapter to whatever framework you're using.  The env.rb above deletes the tmp folder before each test starts.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to take a look at the `sandbox` gem.

```
gem install sandbox
```

Example usage is here: https://github.com/bdimcheff/sandbox